# Adding current follower in the circuit: error

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, simulation, impedance

I have the below circuit and when I add the current follower op-amp circuit it doesn't work.

When I add an ideal op-amp it works, but when changing it to a realistic op-amp it doesn't.

What could be the problem?

Realistic op-amp:
[image: Using Ideal Op Amp]

Ideal op-amp:
[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. Please list error messages or explain why it doesn't work. Give information such as the software you are using and your design objectives.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal op amp has an output voltage over 166 V, which is necessary to supply enough current through R51. There is no way that a real op amp with a supply voltage of 22 V can accomplish this.

Try changing R51 to 1k instead of 10k.

Comment: Ohh yes I didnt notice that. But increasing the R51 will require the op amp to output higher current.
 This circuit current reachs up to 800mA. But I don't think that is it a good idea to put an op amp with an output current of 800mA. 
So is there any other possible solution to solve this problem?